# Conditional formatting in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a way to do conditional formatting in python the way it is in excel?

Example.

Lets say I have the number 5 as average.
If I have a number which is 20% higher than the avaerage I want it to be displayed in the color green

Same for when I have a number which is 20% lower. Than I want the number to be red.

Been trying to figure it out without succes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to understand the context that you want to create the conditional formatting in. If you are referring to formatting data in a pandas dataframe, I think that's impossible. On the other hand, if you're writing your output from python to excel using [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html) then conditional formatting is pretty easy. Though I don't know how to mark 20% above average, the examples [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) show you how to write conditionally formatted cells that are a certain number of standard deviations above average or that are in the top x%. I hope this helps.